# INSERT INTO Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: comments

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

I'm setting up a server for a project that I've been trying to develop on my own, and using SQLite and Node.js as the database type and server platform, respectively. I'm relatively new to backend development, and I am trying to set up a POST request from the frontend of the webpage to the backend so whatever the user submits will store in "comments.db", a file in the server which will store all the username and data (specifically the user ID and data).

In the past, I've tried renaming the database differently, and moving the database into several different subfiles, but I always yield the same error on submission.

The following is my code for my node.js file:

```
var os = require( 'os' );

const interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
 const addresses = [];
 var getMacAddress;



var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var ip = require("ip");
var address = ip.address();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('comments.db');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.get('/comments', function(request, response){
    // response.send('Hello Worlds');
    response.send("Hello my name is aestheticnoodle and you have reached a wrong");
});



app.get('/comments', function(request, response){
    console.log('GET request received at /alpha');
    db.all('SELECT * FROM comments', function(err, rows){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error");
        } else {
            response.send(rows);
            //pass rows back to the client
        }
    });
}); 


//runs once a user submits a comment
app.post('/comments', function(request, response){
    db.run('INSERT INTO comments VALUES (?, ?)', ["aestheticnoodle" ,request.body.action], function(err, rows){
        if(err){
            console.log(request.body.action);
            console.log("INSERT INTO " + err);
        } else {
            response.status(200).redirect('chat.html');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});

var admin = require("firebase-admin");


var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "baseapp",
    authDomain: "fire",
    databaseURL: "inthe,
    projectId: "data",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "private",
    appId: "some2"
  };
  admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);



var headers = {
    'App-Id': 'someappid',
    'App-Key': 'someappkey',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

var dataString = '{"text": "test run.."}';

var options = {
    url: 'https://somesite.com/v2/parse',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

and the error is as follows:

```
C:\Users\achu1\Music\projectsummer2019\cybeRx>node nodeRequest.js
Server is running on port 3000
undefined
INSERT INTO Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: comments
```

here is the javascript snippet where I try to insert html in the interface of a chat bot:

```
var string = "What seems to be the problem you have been experiencing? Use one of the keywords, per <a href = \"symptomlist.html\"  target=\"_blank\"> SymptomList</a> the complete list of symptoms."
        document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML += '<form action = "/comments" method = "POST">'+ "<div id = \"botLog\" class = \"chatting\">" + string + '<textarea rows = "15" name = "comment"> Write stuff here' + '</textarea>'+ '<br><br><input type = "submit" value = "SUBMIT"/></form>' + "</div><br>";
```

as you can see, I attempted to connect my database and my html file running in the `localhost` by making a `POST` method form into my `comment.db` file, which is actually in my directory.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/We1vI.jpg

why does the node say that there is no such database to execute the `POST` command, and how do I resolve this problem so my textbox data saves to the database?